# function returns a function which can only be invoked 2 times

Tags: javascript, callback

I am trying to write a function that returns a function which can be invoked twice(and the result of that is gonna be added together) but not more than twice. Also the result must be isNan as

```
function twice(func) {
  var newFun=function(){
    for (var i=0; i<=2; i++){
      func();
    }
  }
  return newFun;
}

allReturns = twice(function() {
  return 4
});
var result=allReturns()+allReturns()+allReturns();
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!!

Comment: The last sentence of your first paragraph is not finished :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `newFun` function calls the passed function twice during each invocation. You should use a variable and count the function calls.

The following function checks the count of the function calls and returns `0` when the function has been called twice.

```
function twice(func, exceededReturnValue) {
  // the following variable is local to the `twice` function
  var called = 0;
  // return a function that *remembers* the declared variable
  return function() {
     if ( called == 2 ) {
       console.warn('the function has already been called twice');
       return exceededReturnValue;
     }
     called++;
     return func();
  }
}

var allReturns = twice(function() {
  return 4
}, 0);
```

In JavaScript a "function [that] returns a function" is called a *closure*.

In case that the passed function should accept arguments you can use the `.apply` method instead of the invocation operator:

```
return func.apply(null, arguments);
// ...
var allReturns = twice(function(foo) {
  return 4 * (foo || 1);
}, 0); 

// allReturns(8) + allReturns(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to `for (var i=0; i<=2; i++)`, it seems that your function can be invoked thrice, instead of twice. And you did invoke it three times in `var result=allReturns()+allReturns()+allReturns();`. Anyways, this is not a big deal.

Looking at your snippet, what may be the closest to what you have in your mind is [**generator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*). The snippet can be slightly modified as:

```
function twice(func) {
  var newFun = function*() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
      yield func();
    }
  }
  return newFun;
}

var allReturns = twice(function() {
  return 4
})(); // Remember the `()` here. What `twice` returns is a function (in my case a generator), and have to be executed.

var result=allReturns.next().value+allReturns.next().value+allReturns.next().value;
```

and `result` is `12`.

**Generator** is now supported by Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Opera and NodeJS.

Comment: If the function is invoked 3 times, it should print the last one as undefined because the function is supposed to be able to invoked only twice. Also, I have no idea what 'yield' is but I def. can't use that(its part of an exercise)